# Pivot Table calculation

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I would like to calculate a new field which is Dose* quantity.

I have a large dataset (3,000 rows) and the dose variable includes the unit of measurement in the cells. For example, doses are entered as "30 mg" or "5 - 325 mg". How can I use pivot tables to calculate dose*quantity variables while ignoring the "mg" portion?

Comment: Use left(A1,2)*1 assuming 30mg is in cell A1

Comment: I prefer `left(A1,2)+0` as it's easier to remember due to it mirroring my RSVP response to wedding invites.